# Merging data in initialState with preloaded data from server

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a state shape like this (set as initialState on my postReducer):

```
{
  posts: {
    isFetching: false,
    hasFetched: false,
    items: []
  }
}
```

I want to set the `items` array with data preloaded on initial render via embedding JSON in HTML (without over-writing `isFetching` and `hasFetched`) :

```
<script>
  window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(array_with_posts)}
</script
```

Redux documentation guides [recommends](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#the-client-side) handling the preloaded data like this:

```
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
const store =  createStore(
    rootReducer, preloadedState,
    composeWithDevTools(middleware)
);
```

But that would over-write my whole state shape with only the `items` array.

Setting state while running the app, the Redux data flow is comprehensible to me, and setting only a portion of the state works fine. But how do I set only a portion of the state with preloaded data when booting up Redux?

**Update**

For context, currently I'm using `combineReducers()` when creating the store:

```
import posts from './reducers/posts'
import comments from './reducers/comments'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts,
  comments
});

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(middleware)
);
```

Comment: I would help a lot if you provide a [mcve]. Here "complete" means a minimal set of reducers and actions to fully illustrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, I was considering that when writing the question, but I thought that it's so much code and perhaps my case would not need more than what I provided. I'll try to update the question with a minimal setup.

Comment: "Keep it as simple as possible, but no simpler." To me this means that sometimes a MCVE requires a fair amount of code. As long as you can demonstrate that you cannot make it any simpler in order to illustrate the issue, then you are safe including as much code as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create `preloadedState` with the desired shape:

```
const preloadedState = {
    isFetching: false,
    hasFetched: false,
    items: window.__PRELOADED_LOADED_STATE__,
}
```

Comment: That's true, but maintaining state shape both in store configuration and in reducers feels risky.

Comment: @FellowStranger Risky in what way?

Comment: Yea I'm sorry, "risky" is perhaps the wrong word. But as I'm defining each reducer's state shape in the reducer itself - instinctly it doesn't feel obvious to duplicate iit/maintain it in another file. But perhaps I'm overthinking.

Comment: @FellowStranger I think I understand what you are trying to say. If the reducers change in such a way that the state's shape is different, for example, the `items` are now at `state.foo.items`, then you will also need to update `preloadedState`.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your preloaded state is an array as you say, you can merge your results and use that as initial store.

Non Babel solution (no spread object)

```
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
const preMerge = Object.assign({}, counterApp.posts, { items: preloadedState });
const merge = { posts: preMerge };
const store = createStore(merge);
```

Babel solution (with spread object)

```
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
const merge = {
  posts: {
    ...counterApp.posts,
    items: preloadedState,
  },
};
const store = createStore(merge);
```

Also you can use an utility like [_lodash](https://lodash.com/) to do deep object merges (check _lodash.merge method).

**Updated context:**

You have to merge the preloaded state into the rootReducer using any of the ways I explained before. For example, if using Babel and having the posibility of use spread object you can do:

```
import posts from './reducers/posts'
import comments from './reducers/comments'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts,
  comments
});

const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
const preloadStateMergedIntoRootReducer = {
  ...rootReducer,
  posts: {
    ...rootReducer.posts,
    items: preloadedState,
  },
};

const store = createStore(
  preloadStateMergedIntoRootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(middleware)
);
```

As I stated before, you have other options to do it. If you don't want to take in count which attribute of the rootReducer object you need to spread and do deep merges dinamically you can use libraries such the afore mentioned _lodash or for example [Inmutable.js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/mergeDeep) that do the work for you dinamically.

Comment: OK, that's a nice one. I forgot to mention that I'm using `combineReducers()`, so that goes in as a first argument `createStore()`. But I assume the principle is the same somehow?

Comment: I assumed you only had one reducer, but if you had more the workaround can be the same. You can merge data in the result of your `combineReducers()`. And then use it in `createStore`.

Comment: Would you mind adding to your answer how merging data in the result of `combineReducers()` could look like? I have some trouble merge data into the result of `combineReducers()` as it returns a function.

Comment: Update your question with your code where you use combineReducers() and I can try to narrow it a little more.